# defparam for array of modules in verilog

Tags: verilog

I am trying to implement a parametrized special purpose memory with an array of my own defined register.

my_register:

```vhdl
module my_register(clk,
                   data_in,
                   write_enable,
                   equal);

parameter WORD_SIZE = 4;

input                           clk;
input       [WORD_SIZE - 1 : 0] data_in;
input                           write_enable;
output                          equal;

reg [WORD_SIZE - 1 : 0] register;

always @(posedge clk) begin
     if (write_enable)
         register = data_in;
end

assign equal = data_in ^ register;
endmodule
```

in the top module I have:

```vhdl
module my_memory(clk,
                 data_in,
                 write_enable, 
                 matches);

parameter MY_WORD_SIZE = 8;

input                                           clk;
input  [WORD_SIZE - 1 : 0]                      data_in;
input  [(2'b1 << MEMORY_ADDRESS_WIDTH) - 1 : 0] write_enable;
output [(2'b1 << MEMORY_ADDRESS_WIDTH) - 1 : 0] matches;

my_register memory [(2'b1 << MEMORY_ADDRESS_WIDTH) - 1 : 0] (clk, data_in, write_enable, matches);
endmodule
```

but the problem is I can't override the parameter `WORD_SIZE` of `my_register` in the top module.

I tried:

```vhdl
defparam memory.WORD_SIZE = MY_WORD_SIZE;
```

but this does't work and gives an error:

> WORD_SIZE is not declared under prefix memory

Is there a way to override the parameter of an array of custom modules?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `defparam` to override an array of instances in one statement. You would have to repeat the `defparam` for each instance. But there is no need to use `defparam` statements in Verilog-2001 or SystemVerilog. You can pass parameters inline with instantiating statement.

```verilog
module my_memory #(parameter MY_WORD_SIZE = 8) ( 
input                                           clk,
input  [WORD_SIZE - 1 : 0]                      data_in,
input  [(2'b1 << MEMORY_ADDRESS_WIDTH) - 1 : 0] write_enable,
output [(2'b1 << MEMORY_ADDRESS_WIDTH) - 1 : 0] matches
);

my_register #(.WORD_SIZE(MY_WORD_SIZE))
     memory [(2'b1 << MEMORY_ADDRESS_WIDTH) - 1 : 0] (clk, data_in, write_enable, matches);
endmodule
```